# Merge two arrays proprely in a function properties

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm looking for a proper way to merge two array to add into my tracking properties.

This is my function for tracking :

```
const trackEvent = (user, title, properties = {}) => {
  console.log({
   userId: user.cuid,
   event: title,
   properties: { ...properties }
 });
```

};

Then, I've got two examples of two properties I want to merge :

```
export const testProperties = ({  "Color": "Black"});
export const testProperties2 = ({  "Amount": "200"});
```

Then, when I call my function :

```
trackEvent(user, "Mon titre", testProperties );
```

I didn't want the merge array to have an index but to merged. I try to concat them without success.

Comment: In your code you're not showing how you're merging those arrays... should doing `{...testProperties, ...testProperties2}` be sufficient?

Comment: Oh yes ! That's exactly what I was missing... I know it was easy but I was stuck for too long. Thanks, I need to find my braind again!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the two objects into a single one, you should do it before you pass it to the `trackEvent()` function. This can be done by creating a new object and spreading the two objects into it, i.e.:

```
trackEvent(user, "Mon titre", { ...testProperties, ...testProperties2 });
```